# How to append file on HDFS in MapReduce program

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I'm using `CDH-5.14.2-1.cdh5.14.2.p0.3`. And I tried to append some String to an existing file on HDFS.

Then I wrote like below:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
String str = "testtest";
FSDataOutputStream out = fs.append(new Path("tmp/tmp_file"));
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes("utf-8"));
byte[] b = new byte[1024];
int numBytes = 0;
while ((numBytes = in.read(b)) > 0) {
   out.write(b, 0, numBytes);
}
```

There are no errors, but nothing is written to `tmp_file`(`tmp_file` was a blank file). I create `tmp_file` another method by using `fs.create(path)`, so the `tmp_file` was created but append does not go well.

I've read some posts, and I realized that the property `dfs.support.append` must be `true`. So I searched Cloudera Manager, but I couldn't find. Instead I wrote `conf.set("dfs.support.append", "true")`, but It was meaningless.

And I used `IOUtils.copyBytes(in, out, 4096, true)` and `out.writeBytes(String tmp)` but nothing was written.

I searched and find setting below:
[image: setting]

I set like this fig, and `Deplor Client Configuration` and restart all services. But Nothing changed…

Did I mistake?

Comment: Why do you need to append files? Almost all Hadoop libraries can support reading entire directories, so just make a new file in the directory of the other

Comment: I want to use global variables in Mapreduce program. I tried to use tmp_file as a global variable which type is a list<String>.

Comment: You can't use global variables in mapreduce... It's distributed over multiple processes and physical machines. Any fields and local variables will only be scoped to that mapper or reducer task

Comment: By the way, you'll need to flush the outputStream if you want something written to the filesystem

Comment: Thanks, I'll think the other way at the same time.
I’m sorry to ask such a simple things, but where should I specify `out.flush()`?  I wrote after `out.write(b, 0, numBytes)`, nothing has written...

Comment: Well, I don't think that line does what you want... You can just use `out.writeUTF(str)`... Don't need any loops or InputStream

Comment: I wrote `out.writeUTF(str)` instead of a loop, but nothing has written. When I use `fs.create` I can write some strings(Although it will be overwritten), so I think `fs.append` method is a cause. I'll reconsider the algorithm not to use global variables. Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Hmm. Okay. In any case, you're welcome to add file appending into the hdfs-site.xml via Cloudera Manager, but it won't be searchable because it is not exposed by default. You need to find the section of HDFS service that let's you add arbitrary properties

Comment: I set like above post. Are there any mistakes?

Comment: Looks fine. No guarantees it'll work with your other code

Comment: Thanks for your helping.